# Why does scala copy not preserve state from original class instance?

Tags: scala

Seems like copy doesn't preserve any state from the original instance but just uses the base class definition to make a new instance with your new value. Anyone know why it was implemented this way?

```
scala> case class A(){ var y = 2 }
defined class A

scala> val a = new A()
a: A = A()

scala> a.y = 9
a.y: Int = 9

scala> a.y
res9: Int = 9

scala> val b = a.copy()
b: A = A()

scala> b.y
res10: Int = 2
```

Comment: Hi @azuras, a case class is not intended to be mutable in any sense, that's why copy only fallback to constructor arguments, because it isn't really copy the object, but create a new one with the given modifications to the actual.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez would that count as a scala bug? that it lets you add vars then assumes you haven't used them for `copy`

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I wouldn't call it a bug. Scala _(for better or worse)_ is characterized for being flexible. You're allowed to use vars in case classes, even if that's considered a bad practice.

Comment: What LuisMiguelMeíaSuárez said, and then perhaps obviously, to get the behavior you want, declare `case class A(var y: Int = 2)` instead.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez hmmm ... even if it's not a scala bug, I'm betting it will end with avoidable bugs in client code

Comment: @Lasf well it surly will work, but again, that's not idiomatic Scala...

Comment: @JoelBerkeley, mind to expand why you think it will lead to bugs in client code?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez cos it doesn't copy the whole target, only a part of it. That is very easily missed

Comment: @JoelBerkeley well, I'll give you a point in that it isn't a copy in the Java sense, but since case classes are intended to be immutable _(and scala in general encourages immutability)_, it makes sense to just copy the constructor arguments. I think the real problem here is not giving the correct use to the functionality. However, I will agree that the Scala compiler should disallow the use of vars in case classes _(and makes them final, which is another common mistake)_.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley: The Scala Language Specification *very clearly* spells out that `copy` does nothing but forward to the constructor. Ergo, `copy` *cannot possibly* copy anything that is not part of the constructor. Likewise, the SLS also clearly says that pretty much any of the case class "magic" only applies to the "elements" of the case class, which the spec defines as the constructor parameters *and nothing else*. And that is also how case classes are taught in any Scala course I have ever seen, and how they are documented in any Scala book or tutorial I have ever seen.

Answer (score 4):

> Anyone know why it was implemented this way?

This Scala-lang [dialog](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/9587) offers good insight into why it's implemented that way.  In particular, Daniel Sobral's example makes a lot of sense:

> Suppose a variable should contain an unique number, such that no
>   instances have the same number? Or suppose it points to a mutable
>   object -- should it be shared between instances, or copied so that
>   each instance has its own.

Answer (score 3):

That is not a bug nor a mutability issue.

A case class works in a way where all its features (equals, hashcode, toString, copy, etc) are depend on its constructor parameters (some of them don't work with currying).

You will have the same problem although your variable would be a val. For example,

```
case class AAA() {
  val field = 1
}

val instanceA = new AAA() {
  override val field: Int = 5
}

println(instanceA.field)
// 5

println(instanceA.copy().field)
// 1
```

Your case class should be

```
case class A(y:Int = 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but this is how you could accomplish what you want in a idiomatic Scala way.

```
final case class A(a: Int = 2) // if a is not provided it will fallback to the default value of 2
val a = A(a = 3) // A(3)
val b = a.copy(a = 9) // A(9) - BTW, this is the same as A(a = 9)
```

`case classes` are intended for modeling immutable data objects, and the `copy` method is provided as a shortcut when you want to create a new object which share common state with another, so you only need to define the pieces of data you want to change.